# Cacti graph not showing

Tags: php, scripting, cacti

I have created php script for cacti which outputs data in format like: `<variable>:<value>`
Output of my script: `temperature:20 humidity:15`
Then I created data input method where input string is: `php <path_cacti>/scripts/getTempHumData.php <host>`
Script is placed in cacti folder / scripts.
Input field is hostname - in script I use it as $ARGV[0] variable.
Output fields are two - temperature and humidity.
Then I assigned that script to device, added everything it needed, turned off SNMP usage for device. Device status is 'up'.
Then I created graph template and graph and assigned it to graph tree. But graph cannot be seen - it just shows that image cannot be found (that small red x in browser).
I edited my script to pass contant values in the same format, I looked in cacti/log/cacti.log but there is no entries with my host IP.
Also, there are no rrd file which graph needs - in debug mode it tries to create, but there is no rrd file created. Also in data source path rrd file which is pointed does not exists.
How can I solve this error?
Thank You in advance.

Script code:

```
<?php
/*$content = file_get_contents("http://".$ARGV[0]);
$air_temperature = null;
$air_humidity = null;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($content);
$air_temperature = $xml->Item[1]->Value;
$air_humidity = $xml->Item[2]->Value;

echo "temperature:".$air_temperature." humidity:".$air_humidity;*/
echo "temperature:20 humidity:15";
?>
```

RRD file is not created automattically, of course after running command which is given when I turn on debug, I got my rrd file. But NaN values are shown for each needed value.

Comment: Are you running the script as your Cacti user?

Comment: What do You mean by that? I try to run script from command line, it works. And I add my script as data input method.

Comment: You may get a better response on the Cact forums.

Comment: I already asked, but in 24 hours, there is just a few views and no replies.

Comment: Could you show us the output of `ls -al /path/to/cacti/rra`? With the actual path to the cacti directory of course.

Comment: Directory: /var/cacti/rra
There are many directories, but directory with needed rrd file:

drwxrwxrwx     2 cacti  cacti    512 Aug 23 09:15 4267

Comment: For starters, I'd turn on verbose logging and see what result comes back from your DS and post it back here. What's showing the NaN? Graph or the log?

Comment: NaN's are in the graph

Answer (score 1):

There are a wide variety of problems that can cause NaN in Cacti graphs.

The best thing to do is to work through the [debugging checklist in the Cacti documentation](http://www.cacti.net/downloads/docs/html/debugging.html).